# Как создать бота для 3d игры (AI)?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, генетический-алгоритм

Как создать бота для 3d игры (AI)?
Меня волнует один только вопрос: "На каких данных его обучать?".
Игра, к примеру, CS:GO (3d шутер).
Есть местоположение союзников. Обнаружить врага бот может легко (вместо головы текстурка чуть-чуть другая). Но его еще нужно научить бегать и закупать оружие.
К примеру, если на него летит граната, он должен отбежать от неё или отвернуться.
Я знаю про генетический алгоритм. Но не могу представить это в игре. НУ КАК?
Для машинного обучения нужны данные. Какие и где мне их взять?
Так что, тут должен быть задействованы ген. алгоритмы.

Comment: if else :) (как вариант)

Comment: @TEA получится прямолинейный бот

Comment: для шутера боты самый простые вроде бы. А если речь именно про нейронные сети, то можно почитать как это делали в Open AI (бот для доты) Или alpha-go (кратко - боты играли сами с собой, им давали небольшой стартовый толчок а дальше оценочные функции).

Comment: @pavel  не знаю почему, но не могу найти того, как работает OpenAI Five. Везде только новости, что он победил людей

Comment: @HelloWorld https://blog.openai.com/openai-five/ возможно это будет интересно.

Comment: До смешного но Антон николаев прав :3 начните с простого бота для конкретной игры, и на базе его потихоньку развивайте проект.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что для генетического алгоритма достаточно создать нейросети с нейронами, отвечающими за передвижение, стрельбу, поворот. Мне кажется, что ботам в начале достаточно просто передвигаться и при встрече с противником убивать. Потом в течение нескольких игр выбрать лучшие нейросети и скрестить их.

Выбор оружия можно сделать, присвоив каждому оружию число в порядке возрастания (от самого слабого оружия до самого мощного). И если бот имеет оружие более слабое чем у убитого им противника, то меняет его, или если деньги позволяют, то можно купить более сильное оружие.